# Spacing is not working for me in Tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I just started learning Tailwind CSS, all day long I'm trying to understand why space-x-n not working for me
I searched everywhere on Google but no luck

this is my code:

```
<nav class="bg-gray-800">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <div class="flex justify-between">
            <div class="flex space-x-4">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/src/logo.png" style="height:40px;" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="">Features</a>
                    <a href="">Pricing</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>secondary nav</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

this is my app.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

config file

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/Pages/*.vue',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
        screens:{
            sm: '480px',
            md: '768px',
            lg: '976px',
            xl: '1440px'
        }
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
};
```

Comment: The spacing is working fine. Between which elements do you want the space exactly to be?

Comment: @nourhomsi between the logo and the links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspect your generated markup and if there's no `space-x-4`, there might be an error in your build step. It's also possible that this file isn't part of the configured tailwind content files.

You're markup looks correct. Both `gap-x-4` and `space-x-4` should provide a 16px gap between the two contained divs.

You can give the first div containing the logo a `mr-4` margin as workaround.

See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap#changing-row-and-column-gaps-independently

Comment: not working since im using flex

Comment: gap applies to both, flexbox and grid. I just realized, your example code works for me though... both with gap and space.

Comment: very weired it doesnt works for me

Comment: You can always test your markup here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/
Did you do any other customizations to the tailwind config?

Comment: please check my question again, I added the config file

Comment: Hm, nothing unusual for me. Have you checked your browsers web inspector? Is the `space-x-4` class there? Is the property available in the elements css property list?

Comment: doesnt exist when i inspect

Comment: Well then there is something wrong in your compilation. Maybe a cached version is served. Try to rebuild your project or restart your dev server.

Comment: very strange I also restarted the apache and I did npm install && npm run 
same problem 
 also i checked on a different browser + incognito   always same issue

Comment: I found the issue was in my layout.vue   
I dont know why but now I moved the navbar to home.vue inside <layout> and it works

Comment: Where does layout.vue live? Is it part of the configured content files?

Comment: - JS
      - Layouts / AppLayout.vue     and another folder 

        - Pages / Home.vue 

inside home I have <app-layout></app-layout>

and of course in my AppLayout.vue  I have <template><slot/></template>

Comment: Looks like you need to add `'./resources/js/Layouts/*.vue'` to your config file. Your layout.vue was not checked by tailwind for classes. I suspect that the other tailwind classes that worked in this file were already part of other files tailwind did track. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You're very welcome. I would appreciate an accept / upvote of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who still have this issue, As @[andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4952806/andreas) mentioned, just past your code [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/), and check if it's working, if yes, probably you have a compilation problem, other classes may still work since they are already available in the output file.

possible solutions :

1. Make sure your dev server is working and -watching.
2. Clear server cache.
3. Verify the config file ( content prop )